# How do I use html5 local storage in a java applet?

Tags: java, html, applet, local-storage, client-side

In HTML5, one uses local storage to store things on the client's computer, making them persistent beyond a page refresh. Usually, one uses JavaScript to program things on the client-side, but Java applets can be on the client-side too! Thus, I must ask, how do I use local storage from within a Java applet? If it's not possible, then what can I use instead to make things persistent beyond a page refresh?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use LiveConnect to call the JavaScript "HTML5" functions or (since 6u10) use `javax.jnlp.PersistenceService`.